# Windows Server 2012 R2 RDS terminal session constant freeze, disconnects

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, freeze, windows-server-2012

I have installed Windows 2012 R2, using it to support 15 remote desktop users. I have installed Office 2007 open lic. The problem I am having is I start a session, then if I run any Office program, or Internet Explorer, the session will freeze and then get disconnected. Outlook, in particular, will, when run, continually freeze the session every 15 seconds.

If I run the session using a workstation on the local LAN, I get no lockups. If I access over a VPN, then I get the lockups, but only when I run software. Connection Quality tool is usually 2 bars, but ping latency both ways on VPN connection is 36ms. I note that sometimes the connection quality shows no bars when it comes back on, then back to 2. If I do nothing in the session, just leave the remote desktop open, it never disconnects.

Any ideas here?

Comment: How are you licensing office on the rds server? ONE Office 2007 Open License? http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2010/08/16/licensing-office-on-remote-desktop-services.aspx

Comment: Open license, only way to do it. Freezing does not happen with other application only Office and Internet explorer. Run the app, click around, freeze 15s then disconnect, then off around again.

Comment: Sorry type, 15 user volume license Microsoft Office 2007 Standard.

Comment: Experimenting with this it turns out the issue is with the RDP client. Version 6.1.7601 works flawlessly, anything above this has above issues. I have a suspicion that KB2574819 maybe involved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was that the latest RDP clients use both TCP **and** UDP. It is the increased UDP stream that tripped the DOS defence on the Draytek firewall we have in place. We increased the UDP flood defence threshold to 2000 packets per second. Before this the timeout would kick in and stop the UDP packets from flowing, hence the freezing. Post fix no problems smooth as silk.